# google-people resource name change

Tags: google-people-api

It was mentioned in the release docs, that resource name for People API are subject to change. Although there was no clear mention of what can trigger this resourceName change. If we have to use People API instead of Contact API going forward we need a reliable Id to uniquely identify People API object. If there is ambiguity regarding the resourceName and they can change from under us we cannot recommend using Google suite to our customers.